# previous_posts_link and next_posts_link, how to return the next/previous post's title as the url

Tags: urls, title, next-post-link, previous-post-link

The site I am working on needs to have the returned url set a specific way. That being said, all posts are basically images that are posted, with there titles being said as the page urls.  How do I go about getting the returned url from next_posts_link() and previous_posts_link to be returned as mysite.com/posttitle ?

At this point I have two divs wrapped with divs and spans. located within the loop

```
  <div class="back-nav">     
                <span class="button-nav-previous">
                 <?php previous_posts_link( '',0); ?>
                </span>
            </div>
```

currently this is returning mysite/title/page/2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions you are using refer to the next or prev paginated set of posts, not a single post,  hence the format they are in. Try using `get_adjacent_post()` instead.

```
<?php
    $prev = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true)
    $next = get_adjacent_post(false, '', false)

    //use an if to check if anything was returned and if it has, display a link
    if($prev){
        $url = get_permalink($prev->ID);            
        echo '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $prev->post_title . '">Previous Post</a>';
    }

    if($next) {
        $url = get_permalink($next->ID);            
        echo '<a href="' . $url . '" title="' . $next->post_title . '">Next Post</a>';
    } 
?>
```

You can read more about `get_adjacent_posts()` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post).

This should be noted that the get_adjacent_post() function is intended to be used on a single detail page. If you are using this on a posts page it may behave unexpectedly.

Comment: Basically it'll be the landing page of the site as it flips through posts. So does that mean we should avoid using the above and stick to a custom function (I've currently got one created in functions.php)?

Comment: This was what i am searching, thanks a lot, you saved my day Cheers !!